# Detach GCP persistent disk from source snapshot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

After creating a disk from a source snapshot and deleting the snapshot, the disk continues to show a source snapshot, even though that doesn't exist anymore.

Is this something that's going to get cleaned up at some point? It's not clear what purpose that attribute has on the disk object. It also messes up the Terraform configuration by requiring a parameter that's not needed in "regular" disks created from scratch.

Because of this attribute, Terraform wants to recreate the disk. Maybe this is a bug in the GCP provider.

Comment: AFAIK that is just an attribute (notation). The same indication appears if you create a disk from an image. Edit your question with details on how this causes Terraform problems.

Comment: How was the disk created? By Terraform or manually using the CLI or GUI? If you modify a resource outside Terraform, it will usually want to delete and recreate that resource to match the saved state. Edit your question with details, context and the HCL.

Comment: It's complicated. Disk created by terraform, delete through console after taking a snapshot, new disk created from snapshot and imported back into terraform in place of the old disk. Terraform identified the source snapshot as a difference that requires resource replacement.

Comment: Inconvenient, but you cannot change resources managed or imported by Terraform. There are advanced techniques to manage/recover from this problem. Basically you would need to change the persistent disk from being a resource to being data (that is imported) in the HCL. That is an entirely different problem. I recommend creating a feature request at Google's Issue Tracker on this item.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same thing. What did you end up doing?

Comment: Specify the snapshot in code.